# Concatenating Pandas dataframe obtained through pd.dummies doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This might be appropriate for a github issue, a bug maybe?, but I first wanted to make sure I am not doing something wrong.

I have a dataframe comprised of y, 2 indipendent variables and an offset (i am fitting a Poisson regression)

```
df_Data_clim_monthly_0

        var1        offset      var2        y        month
1236    141.858643  27.862616   0.149570    0.000000    1
1237    143.881744  25.166234   0.304853    0.000000    2
1238    130.819931  27.862616   0.385182    0.000000    3
1239    121.556984  26.963822   0.790843    0.135135    4
1240    100.683868  27.862616   1.604284    0.243243    5
1241    56.976879   26.963822   1.440580    0.135135    6
1242    41.691605   27.862616   1.474398    0.108108    7
1243    39.375465   27.862616   1.377272    0.243243    8
1244    37.733364   26.963822   2.826061    0.486486    9
1245    62.874672   27.862616   1.225250    0.055556    10
1246    106.758812  26.963822   0.456604    0.054054    11
1247    138.216904  27.862616   0.161243    0.030303    12
1440    75.941811   27.862616   1.041132    0.000000    1
1441    76.770737   25.166234   1.234092    0.058824    2
1442    69.535652   27.862616   1.594425    0.054054    3
1443    51.365620   26.963822   2.005312    0.000000    4
1444    32.005558   27.862616   3.069238    0.054054    5
1445    23.987453   26.963822   6.779000    0.108108    6
1446    15.179461   27.862616   5.729475    0.135135    7
1447    16.316160   27.862616   6.272911    0.081081    8
1448    21.942101   26.963822   5.712628    0.027027    9
1449    37.506062   27.862616   2.465134    0.055556    10
1450    51.930992   26.963822   1.180570    0.027027    11
1451    64.261795   27.862616   0.834773    0.000000    12
```

the index doesn't start from 0 because it was cropped from a larger dataset.

I want to introduce an interactive term for the month - to see if seasonality is significant in my fit, I need a dummy variable, that represents the change from JFM, AMJ, JAS, OND.

In order I do (maybe not elegantly but it works):

```
df_months3 = deepcopy(df_Data_clim_monthly_0.month)
df_months3[(df_months3==2)|(df_months3==3)]=1
df_months3[(df_months3==5)|(df_months3==6)]=4
df_months3[(df_months3==8)|(df_months3==9)]=7
df_months3[(df_months3==11)|(df_months3==12)]=10
```

and then

```
df_dummies3 = pd.get_dummies(df_months3,prefix='month')
```

if I print df_dummies3.head(), looks great

```
      month_1  month_4  month_7  month_10
1236        1        0        0         0
1237        1        0        0         0
1238        1        0        0         0
1239        0        1        0         0
1240        0        1        0         0
```

I then multiply the dummy variables with a series (I want to use only the interactive terms in my regression)

```
df_dummies3var1  = df_dummies3.mul(df_Data_clim_monthly_0['var1'], axis=0)
df_dummies3var2  = df_dummies3.mul(df_Data_clim_monthly_0['var2'], axis=0)
```

Rename the indexes to avoid columns with same labels:

```
df_dummies3var2 = df_dummies3var2.rename(index=str, 
         columns={"month_1": "var2_month1", "month_4": "var2_month4","month_7": "var2_month7", "month_10": "var2_month10"})

df_dummies3var1 = df_dummies3var1.rename(index=str, 
         columns={"month_1": "var1_month1", "month_4": "var1_month4", "month_7": "var1_month7", "month_10": "var1_month10"})
```

Things look right, if I print the head()

```
      var2_month1  var2_month4  var2_month7  var2_month10
1236     0.149570     0.000000          0.0           0.0
1237     0.304853     0.000000          0.0           0.0
1238     0.385182     0.000000          0.0           0.0
1239     0.000000     0.790843          0.0           0.0
1240     0.000000     1.604284          0.0           0.0
      var1_month1  var1_month4  var1_month7  var1_month10
1236   141.858643     0.000000          0.0           0.0
1237   143.881744     0.000000          0.0           0.0
1238   130.819931     0.000000          0.0           0.0
1239     0.000000   121.556984          0.0           0.0
1240     0.000000   100.683868          0.0           0.0
```

I concatenate these two:

```
df_dummies3tot = pd.concat([df_dummies3var1, df_dummies3var2], axis=1)
```

This works. I have a 8 column dataframe. (hard to copy and paste the head of this dataframe)

```
     var1_month1  var1_month4  var1_month7  var1_month10  var2_month1  \
1236   141.858643     0.000000          0.0           0.0     0.149570   
1237   143.881744     0.000000          0.0           0.0     0.304853   
1238   130.819931     0.000000          0.0           0.0     0.385182   
1239     0.000000   121.556984          0.0           0.0     0.000000   
1240     0.000000   100.683868          0.0           0.0     0.000000   

      var2_month4  var2_month7  var2_month10  
1236     0.000000          0.0           0.0  
1237     0.000000          0.0           0.0  
1238     0.000000          0.0           0.0  
1239     0.790843          0.0           0.0  
1240     1.604284          0.0           0.0
```

Now I want to concatenate the variable dataframe and this one, I want it to be in the same dataframe to pass it to smf.poisson.
They have the same index and the same number of rows. 
But if I do

```
dftot = pd.concat([df_Data_clim_monthly_0[['var1','offset','var2','y']],
        df_dummies3tot],axis=1)
```

dftot has the correct amount of columns (12), but double the number of rows, and essentially the concatenation has put the two dataframe one of top of each other and filled the rows with nan.

```
print dftot.head()
           var1     offset   var2       y          var1_month1  var1_month4  \
1236  141.858643  27.862616  0.149570   0.000000          NaN          NaN   
1237  143.881744  25.166234  0.304853   0.000000          NaN          NaN   
1238  130.819931  27.862616  0.385182   0.000000          NaN          NaN   
1239  121.556984  26.963822  0.790843   0.135135          NaN          NaN   
1240  100.683868  27.862616  1.604284   0.243243          NaN          NaN   

      var1_month7  var1_month10  var2_month1  var2_month4  var2_month7  \
1236          NaN           NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
1237          NaN           NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
1238          NaN           NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
1239          NaN           NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
1240          NaN           NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   

      var2_month10  
1236           NaN  
1237           NaN  
1238           NaN  
1239           NaN  
1240           NaN  


print dftot.tail()
      var1      offset  var2        y     var1_month1  var1_month4  \
9995    NaN     NaN      NaN        NaN     0.000000     0.000000   
9996    NaN     NaN      NaN        NaN   168.764008     0.000000   
9997    NaN     NaN      NaN        NaN   170.622360     0.000000   
9998    NaN     NaN      NaN        NaN   147.312576     0.000000   
9999    NaN     NaN      NaN        NaN     0.000000   115.417694   

      var1_month7  var1_month10  var2_month1  var2_month4  var2_month7  \
9995          0.0    157.737946     0.000000     0.000000          0.0   
9996          0.0      0.000000     0.287053     0.000000          0.0   
9997          0.0      0.000000     0.357397     0.000000          0.0   
9998          0.0      0.000000     0.753133     0.000000          0.0   
9999          0.0      0.000000     0.000000     1.374954          0.0   

      var2_month10  
9995      0.200327  
9996      0.000000  
9997      0.000000  
9998      0.000000  
9999      0.000000
```

Is it something obvious that I am doing wrong, or this is some sort of a bug?

Comment: `df_Data_clim_monthly_0[['var1','offset','var2','y']].join(df_dummies3tot)`

Comment: To get the quarter-of-year more cleanly: `df.month.sub(1).floordiv(3).add(1))`

Comment: i found the issue! the problem is that the multiplication method with the dummy variable transforms the index type. It goes from <class 'pandas.core.indexes.numeric.Int64Index'> to <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> I guess I will post it on github.

Comment: At the end I solved the issue by using .reset_index() I couldn't reproduce the error with other made up data, so I am not sure what the actual issue is.